# Ember.js: How can I test Express server mock?

Tags: unit-testing, express, testing, ember.js

I have a simple `express` server running in my Ember app for development purpose. I created it with the command `ember g http-mock`.

So in my app I have this directory:

```
my-app
  server
    mocks
      posts.js
```

How can I make a *unit* test that runs `posts.js` mock?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally unit tests are for testing small chunks of code that don’t involve network access. If you’re wanting to test UI code that hits your mocks, acceptance tests are a better way to go. But those tests don’t run the express mocks.

Instead, what folks often do is use [ember-cli-mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) to build our a fake server (like mocks allow) and then run the fake server when building their acceptance tests.

Does that help with your question?